# Subversion plugin for Matlab for Windows

Tags: svn, matlab

I am looking for a plugin for Matlab to integrate with subversion.  Ideally an equivalent of Ankh for Visual Studio, something that would put icons in Matlab's directory browser indicating the file's status.  Is there such a thing?  The only solution that I have found so far is [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11596-subversion-interface-for-matlab), which does not work on Windows.

Comment: The claim is that it has not been *tested* under Windows *by the author*. Did you try it out?

Comment: offtopic, not programming related.

Comment: @Anre yes, I have tried it.  Also, there are comments further down on the page complaining how it doesn't work on windows.  Besides, this thing was last updated 3 years ago.  Matlab has changed since, and so has Windows.

Comment: @Svisstack How is a question about programming tools not programming related?

Comment: @Dima: there is http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for these discussions.

Comment: @Andre Exactly.  "Programmers" is for discussions of subjective open-ended questions.  I have asked a very specific question which has an answer.  Either there is a plugin that works on Windows or there isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any such plugin. However, if you need something to check whether the files on your path have changed, and to look at the differences between the files without leaving Matlab and starting the Explorer with TortoiseSVN, I can suggest [this GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23508-subversion-gui) which I've written.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but sounds interesting.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need an SCC compliant SVN wrapper, per Mathworks support. Tortoise for one has an SCC wrapper for subversion. Check out the links here for other alternatvies.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-3TABI8/?solution=1-3TABI8

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple MATLAB script for accessing the TortoiseSVN API on Windows http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24307-tortoise-svn-wrapper